# What is possible and not is with Prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic, boolean

I'm new to Prolog and to logic paradigm development, but I think this can help me in my application. My first doubt is what can I do this with the language.

I'm doing some text processing/natural language processing and I think that my code will be clearer and easy doing it in a logical language than in Java (that is what I'm using and will integrate with Prolog).

My first goal now is discover the char type of a String (alphabetic, digit, numeric, etc...). I have four mais arguments: hasLetter, hasDigit, hasSymbol, hasPunctuation.

With Prolog, I can have one method `determineType()` that will return me the type based on this four attributes or it only with single tests, thinkgs like `isDigit()`, `isAlphabetic()`, etc?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't quite transitioned from "imperative" to "logical" thinking. In Prolog there is never a return value - all that you get is if a predicate succeeded or failed. The arguments of a predicate aren't inputs or outputs, but variables to be unified. Unification is the only way to "return" results in Prolog. Just thought I'd throw my two cents worth in.

Comment: telekinisis, molecular manipulation, premonition? xD You should check the libraries of the prolog system you are using, there are usually tons of hidden goodies.

Answer (score 3):

The category or "type" of each character is a relation, relating a character to its type. You can code it in Prolog using a predicate. A meaningful name for such a predicate would for example be: "character_type(C, T)". In SWI-Prolog, check out the library predicates char_type/2 and code_type/2 to get this information. You can use them for obtaining the type(s) of a character (on backtracking, alternative solutions may be generated) as well as for testing whether a character belongs to a supplied category. For language processing, you may also find definite clause grammars (DCGs) useful.